# Why Does Status Snap?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on a discord app and making the status change. I am working on getting it to have command and then a message. Below the command works but for some reason the "This is a test" snaps and sometimes will show 2 times? Can someone get me going, I have been trying to crack this a while now

When I say "snap" I meant it shows them but at one moment like switches really fast and snaps between the 2.

```
function testbotstatus() {
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | Hello Everyone!');
    }, 3000);
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | This is a test');
    }, 3000);
}
```

-------------EDIT-----------------

```
I have also tried the code below but now it makes the top line "Hello Everyone" snap?

function testbotstatus(client) {
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | Hello Everyone!');
    }, 3000);
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | This is a test');
    }, 6000);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `setInterval`? May you also explain what you mean by "snaps"?

Comment: Is your goal to set activity to `Hello Everyone!` and `This is a test` alternately every 3 second?

Comment: Your edit doesn't help us. We still don't know what you want, or what snap means.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to stack overflow and missed the comments here. by "snaps" I mean it will show "Hello Everyone" go to show "This is a test" but does for like .1 seconds and then goes back to "Hello Everyone" and then will waits a while then shows "This is a test". But doesn't seem to matter about time because whatever I put there is doesn't seem to follow

Comment: is setActivity the correct method? looking at the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) it looks like its meant to be used for something else, *snap*'s might be built into its behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You send 2 request in the same time, you need like:

```js
function testbotstatus(client) {
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | Hello Everyone!');
    }, 3000);
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | This is a test');
    }, 6000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the requests at the same time. Here is a solution that sets you status every 30 seconds that creates a `wait` method, allowing you to wait until x time (In milliseconds) has passed until executing the code below

```js
const wait = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

function async testbotstatus(client) {
    while(true) {
        client.user.setActivity('$help | Hello Everyone!');
        await wait(30000) // This waits 30s before executing again
        client.user.setActivity('$help | This is a test');
        await wait(30000) // Same here
    };
}
```

Comment: You could just use a `while(true)` loop instead of `setInterval(..., 1)`